# using JSON to retrieve images

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am making a chemistry quiz app. the questions need to be in the form of images because of the molecules. below is the part of the code I am having problems with:

```
func getconcept1questions() -> [Concept1Questions] {
    // chercher json file
    var questions:[Concept1Questions] = [Concept1Questions]()

    // chercher json array de dictionaires
    let jsonobjects: [NSDictionary] = self.getjsonfile()

    var index:Int
    for index = 0;
        index < jsonobjects.count; index++
    {
            // json dictionaire actuel
            let jsondictionary:NSDictionary = jsonobjects[index]

            // creer un objet question
            var questionobject:Concept1Questions = Concept1Questions()

            // assigner les valuers de chaque couple à l'objet question
            questionobject.question = UIImage(named: jsondictionary["question"] as! String)
            questionobject.answer = UIImage(named: jsondictionary["answer"] as! String)
            questions.append(questionobject)
    }
```

basically, the purpose of this function is to get the questions (which are images) from the json file. in the json file, the names are strings, for example:

```
"question":"conceptquestion1",
answer":"conceptanswer1"
```

the images are saved in image assets in Xcode project.

At this line of code specifically, I receive an error message:

```
// assigner les valuers de chaque couple à l'objet question
questionobject.question = UIImage(named: jsondictionary["question"] as! String)
questionobject.answer = UIImage(named: jsondictionary["answer"] as! String)
```

The error message says:

> "can not assign a value of type "UIImage?" to type "String"

any ideas on how to get the son to display an image? i just need it to recognize that the data it is searching should match the file name of the image i have saved in the image assets folder.

I have another function to get the json file (the function that is called above in line 8). Here is that function, just incase it may help:

```
func getjsonfile() -> [NSDictionary] {
    // faire un objet nsurl qui dirige vers le fichier json dans notre app bundle
    let appBundlePath:String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("concept1", ofType: "json")

    // ici on utilise optional binding pour verifier qu'il y a bien une voie vers le fichier
    if let realbundlepath = appBundlePath {
        // la voie existe
        let urlpath:NSURL? = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: realbundlepath)

        if let realurlpath = urlpath {
            // l'objet USURL a été bien creé. maintenant on cree l'objet NSDATA
            let jsondata:NSData? = NSData(contentsOfURL: realurlpath)

            if let realjsondata = jsondata {
                // nsdata existe. utiliser nsjsonserialization pour parser le data et creer l'array
                let arrayofdictionaries:[NSDictionary]? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(realjsondata, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! [NSDictionary]?

                if let realarrayofdictionaries = arrayofdictionaries {
                    // on a reussi a parser l'array de diccionaires
                    return realarrayofdictionaries
                }
```

Comment: So what type is questionObject.answer and questionObject.question? According to the compiler the compiler thinks they are strings. If they are not strings then find out why the compiler thinks they are. If they are strings then what are you doing trying to assigning an image to a string?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know IOS development but I do know JSON.

What you can do is encode your images in base64. This will give you a long string that you can put as json data.

You can use this website that encodes images into base64 strings http://www.base64-image.de/

There might already be libraries in your IOS language that encode/decode base64 strings.

It's a pretty common thing to do. This allows you to carry your image as string data rather than in binary form.

Hope it helps!

Update:

A quick google search revealed that Swift has functions to encode images and decode base64 strings.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/swift-code/base64-encode-decode-swift.html